# A bug with the tag badge tracker vanishing

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I was on my profile and wanted to look at the tag badge tracker, I selected it in the drop down and the graphics below the point graph disappeared! So I can't go back to the privilege tracker and I can't see the tag badge tracker.

[image]

I am running:

**OS**

- OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5

**Browser**

- Google Chrome version 45.0.2454.101

**Extensions**

- AdBlock version 2.40.1
- Google Docs version 0.9
- Google Docs Offline version 0.5
- Google Mail Checker version 4.4.0
- New Tab Redirect version 3.1.4 (not enabled)
- Print Friendly & PDF version 2.3

Comment: Could you edit this to explain the version / build of your web browser and your OS? Tracking bugs without knowing those details can be onerous. Also, a chorus of "list your extensions and blockers and user scripts" is likely to follow if you don't disclaim that up front.

Comment: @bmike, fixed the post!

Comment: Well done - The site developers will be able to see the bug tag and have a look - sometimes it takes a while though, but my experience is someone that uses Chrome will usually chime in if they can reproduce the issue or get you a work around if it's a configuration issue on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There used to be an issue where, if your account had no activity in any badge, and you opened the tag badge selector, your tag badge tracker would become hidden and you couldn't select a new tag badge. This is apparently what happened to your profile.

I've reset the tracker for your profile so you can select a tag badge now.

Comment: It happened again.